# StateHasChanged not re renders component quickly in Blazor

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

StateHasChanged method not re render the component once the collection removed. We are tried to Re render the component once the collection item is updated by using **StateHasChanged** but it executes the next statement. After completion of the all lines then only component re renders.

**Main goal is :**
I want to detect the button deletion once its updated in the UI. So, if StateHasChanged method re render the component then UI will be updated.

Code block

```
@if (Collection.Count > 0)
{
 <div>
     
     @for (var i = 0; i< Collection.Count; i++) {
        <button @onclick=@(() => OnDeleteClick())>@Collection[i]</button>
     }
  </div>
}

@code{

private List<string> Collection = new List<string>();

public class DelArgs
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Collection.Add("Chai");
        Collection.Add("Chang");
        Collection.Add("Ikura");
        Collection.Add("Anna");
    }

    private async Task OnDeleteClick()
    {
        Collection.RemoveAt(0);
        StateHasChanged();
        Console.WriteLine("Item Deleted!!");
    }
}`
```

Comment: Unclear. StateHasChanged() is almost the last line in OnDeleteClick, so what does "After completion of the all lines then only ..."  mean exactly?    Is this the exact code?

Comment: Consider providing a [mre]. The answers will only be as good as the question.

Comment: `private async void ` - this might be the problem - don't do this. It should always be `private async Task`. This returns a Task that the runtime can wait for. Otherwise it's not really going to work

Comment: @Quango - because of  `async void` the StatehasChanged() is required. Besides that,  `void` , `async void` and `async Task` should all work here. The real problem was not posted.

Comment: `async void` [should still not be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). You're not returning the task so it *might* run it might not. It's bad practice to use the wrong approach

Comment: Changed to *async Task* but having same issue.

Comment: Told you not to call StateHasChanged, but you still insist on calling it. Why ? Your code, I mean the original code is working. I believe that I understand you now: DO YOU WANT THE COMPONENT TO RE-RENDER ONCE the StateHasChanged method has been called, before Console.WriteLine("Item Deleted!!"); is executed ?